# recover from rescue mode

Tags: grub2

I have installed windows 8 then linux in dual boot in my laptop.  Windows installed on C drive and linux on D drive.
One day extremly I have format the linux drive D dtive from windows it was the succesful operation but after reboot the windows i have got the grub> window and I can't do anything  and I don't have any cd of llinux or windows to boot from it , so any body please tell me how to remove it .?
I don't have knowledge about grub so I didn't try any thing..
There is no menu fo 'c' and when i type 
root (hd0,0)
it says "file system type unknown, partition type 0x7.
I formated the D drive in NTFS which contains linux data that is the reson of it.

Answer (score 0):

At the grub prompt (if it gives you a menu, hit 'c' first), I believe you can type:

```
root (hd0,0)
makeactive
chainloader --force +1
boot
```

That should get you back into windows. You may need to use the 'ls' command at the prompt to figure out which hd you need.

Once in windows, open an elevated command prompt, and issue the following commands:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

After this, you should be able to boot back into windows normally.

Comment: Thanxx for it.
But  how can I remov linux permanently??

Comment: It didn't remove grub window still on startup grub window comes & when i give commands then it goes to windows